# Where to put the ending delimiter in a Regex ?

Tags: php, regex

Im quite terrible at regex! can you guys show me where to put the ending delimiter in this piece of code?

```
$data = preg_replace("/ href=\"\/i", " href=\"{$domain}/", $data);
$data = preg_replace("/ src=\"\/i", " href=\"{$domain}/", $data);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of this regex, what are you trying to find? And what are you trying to replace it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is as follows:

```
preg_replace("/PATTERN/FLAGS", "Replace String", $subject);
```

As you can see, the delimiters are around a **pattern**, so in your case, your delimiters are in place.

However, you also placed a delimiter in the **replace string** argument, which you shouldn't have. You also need to escape characters like the backslash `\`. So the correct form would be:

```
$data = preg_replace("/ href=\"\\/i", " href=\"{$domain}\\", $data);
$data = preg_replace("/ src=\"\\/i", " href=\"{$domain}\\", $data);
```

That code will replace any instance of `href="\` with `href="DOMAIN\`.

However, for that particular piece of replacement, RegEx is not necessary. You could use a simple `str_replace()`:

```
$data = str_replace('href="\\', "href=\"{$domain}\\", $data);
$data = str_replace('src="\\', "src=\"{$domain}\\", $data);
```